# Using capsh to drop all capabilities

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities, capsh

I'm trying to use capsh to grant myself a shell with no capabilities at all with a certain user. This is so I can test security stuff related to being non-root but with only certain capabilities.

Basically I'd like to get a shell running with something similar to this. This would emulate the state under which the test program runs.

```
capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=10101(u0_a101)
gid=10101(u0_a101)
groups=9997(everybody),50101(all_a101)
```

Then I'd like to be able to run capsh again to grant the user some capabilities and/or change uid/gid if it's at all possible.

I haven't found any good tutorials on capsh if anyone has a good reference.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/capsh.1.html

Answer (score 5):

1. List current capabilities

   ```
   capsh --print
   Current: =
   Bounding set=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,[...]
   Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
    secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
    secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
    secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
   uid=1000(user)
   gid=1000(user)
   groups=4(adm),10101(u0_a101)
   ```
2. Drop all capabilities from `1.` *Bounding* section:

   ```
   capsh --drop=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,[...]
   ```

3. + switch user and group:

   ```
   capsh --gid=10101 --drop=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,[...] --uid=10101
   ```

4. + join groups

   ```
   capsh --gid=10101 --drop=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,[...] \
   --uid=10101 --groups=9997,50101
   ```

5. + execute application

   ```
   capsh --gid=10101 --drop=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,[...] \
   --uid=10101 --groups=9997,50101 -- -c 'ping 127.0.0.1'
   ```